# Optional parameter in Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovyscriptengine, groovysh

I have a script that simply does

```
// TODO: assign default value if not defined
println optionalParameter
```

When I invoke it using:

```
new GroovyShell(new Binding([optionalParameter: 'text'])).evaluate(script)
```

it works fine. But if I run it without a parameter like below:

```
new GroovyShell().evaluate(script)
```

it fails with `MissingPropertyException`.

**How can I assign default value for `optionalParameter` so that I don't get `MissingPropertyException`?**

Comment: If the script can be modified you can add "def optionalParameter" at the beginning.

Comment: Or add: `new Binding([].withDefault { 'default' })`

Comment: @Gabriel I can only modify a script. `def optionalParameter` doesn't work as it just declares new variable that is hiding original one

Comment: @Opal I can only modify a script

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code to script works for me:

```
String value
if (binding.hasVariable('optionalParameter')) {
    value = binding.getVariable('optionalParameter')
} else {
    value = 'defaultValue'
}
println value
```

Comment: Can that not be simplified to `optionalParameter = optionalParameter ?: 'defaultValue'`? I believe declaring variables without specifying a type or `def` assigns the variable to the binding.

Comment: Then I'm getting `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: optionalParameter `